# Can't see product images in admin, also missing Browse Files and Upload Files

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, product-images

I can see all product images at the store level, but can NOT see any images in the admin area! Furthermore when I create a new product under admin, the "Browse Files..." and "Upload Files..." buttons are also missing.

I checked the `var/log/system.log` and see the following error each time i go to view the image tab:

`2016-08-19T13:38:08+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/media/uploader.phtml`

Could this be a file/folder permission issue?

Has anyone seen this issue?

Missing "Browse Files..." and "Upload Files..." buttons
[image]

This is what I see!
It's missing "Browse Files...", "Upload Files..." buttons and none of the  images are showing up. 
[image]

**NOTE: New Discovery**
Looking at the error log, I realized folder `media/` and files `media/editor.phtml` and `media/uploader.phtml` do not exist! So I got them from the original Magento 1.9.1. and placed them under `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/`.

The images showed up, But I am still missing the the "Browse Files..." and "Upload Files..." buttons.

Now I am trying to figure which files or folders are missing, to bring that functionality back.

**Solved** the disappearance of the buttons issue also.
While searching I found this [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/Magento-1-9-1-0-admin-image-upload-button-and-browse-file-are/td-p/28816) and found out that I am also missing another folder and it's content. `skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/` which contained the 3 files `flex.swf`, `uploader.swf` and `uploaderSingle.swf`.  Once I copied this folder the buttons appeared.

Also pursuant to the above mentioned article media folder should exist in the following folders:

> skin/adminhtml/default/default
>       /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/system/storage
>       /js/tiny_mce/plugins/
>       design/adminhtml/default/default/template/

Comment: First try to check this in google chrome (because chrome has built-in support for flash). If every thing is working fine in chrome, then you need to update flash support for browser in which the problem is appearing.

Comment: I tried chrome.  It produces the same results.

Comment: Any others suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read the question for more details.
**media** folder should exist in the following folders:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/system/storage
/js/tiny_mce/plugins/
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/
```

In my case somehow all media folders were deleted!

Comment: This is due to incorrect `.gitignore`. It has `media/`, and should `/media`

Answer (score 5):

Please check flash player is installed in your browser or not. If not then install flash player.

Comment: Yes. It has Flash Version 22.0.0.209.  Any other reason why this is not working?

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be due to many reasons:

- wrong permissions set to uploaded files
  Solution: Open lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php and make sure following permissions are set at **`chmod($destinationFile, 0666);`**. This code will be at around line 219.
- At around line: 541, check whether following code exists:

  **`if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {`**
- If still same issue persists, then rename .htaccess file to .htaccess.old in /media folder of magento.

**Note:** In both cases, you may need to flush cache before rechecking.

- If still issue persists, then follow this tutorial:

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/

Please let me know if you still find any problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I tired, changing line 219 from `chmod($destinationFile, 0640);` to `chmod($destinationFile, 0666);` and also changed line 541 from `if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0750, true))) {` to `if (!(@is_dir($destinationFolder) || @mkdir($destinationFolder, 0777, true))) {` with out any luck!  I then renamed htacces.  Still do no not get any images nor the add image link!  I cleared cache after each step. What should the permissions to `media`,  `media/catalog`,  `media/catalog/product` folders and ultimately the image file be?

Comment: I followed `blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/` also, with no luck.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Chrome updated its settings for Flash.  I went into my Flash settings in Chrome, then found the security settings.  I added the 2 Magento domains that I work Admin in to the "allowed sites".

Doing this, I then refreshed the page and viola, the image editing showed up.

Seemed this was a Chrome issue as the Image uploader was working for me in INternet Explorer, just not Chrome.

Comment: Yup, this just happened to me with chrome 69, but I never got a prompt from chrome asking me to allow flash on the backend. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a very long time trying to find out what was going on here especially a I'm not a developer... Anyway my problem was due to a rewrite of:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml

by another extension ( a permission one).

Anyway hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the images doesnt work just in Chrome in Firefox the management of images is working fine, searching on the web i find this tutorial to enable Flash on Chrome https://helpx.adobe.com/br/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html after this is all working fine on Chrome, i wish this help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the flash player for your backend website.

Click on the locker in the navigation bar:

[image]

Select "Site settings" and there enable the Flash site support:

[image]

Refresh the page and you should be able to see the Image loader correctly.